# What are the possible ways to override a function in Magento2?

Tags: magento2

How can I override a constructor in Magento2? I want to override the `execute` function of `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost` class. And while doing that I want to use `Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface` for **changing customers group**. I can use `objectManager` but that is not recommended. So what are the other ways?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do that:

1. create a new module, create a new class that would extend from `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost` and override constructor and `execute` method,
2. use a plugin, since the `execute` method is public, then you can inject `Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface` inside the plugin constructor.

The second option is much easier, go with that. You can read more about plugins [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html). There is no example with constructor, but you can add it and dependency injection would work there as usual.